# Is there a python module that provides deeper analysis of a data structure than pprint?

Tags: python

Is there anything in python that lets me dump out a random object in such a way as to see its underlying data representation?

I am coming from Perl where Data::Dumper does a reasonable job of letting me see how a data structure is laid out. Is there anything that does the same thing in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `Dumper` in Perl gives you a representation of an object that can be `eval`'d by the interpreter to give you the original object. An object's `repr` in Python tries to do that, and sometimes it's possible. A `dict`'s `repr` or a `str`'s `repr` do this, and some classes like `datetime` and `timedelta` also do this. So `repr` is as much the equivalent of `Dumper` but it's not pretty and doesn't show you the internals of an object. For that you can use `dir` and roll your own printer.

Here's my shot at a printer that would not result in `eval`-able Python code and thus should be used to generate a string of the object instead:

```
def dump(obj):
  out = {}

  for attr in dir(obj):
    out[attr] = getattr(obj, attr)

  from pprint import pformat
  return pformat(out)

class myclass(object):
  foo = 'foo'

  def __init__(self):
    self.bar = 'bar'

  def __str__(self):
    return dump(self)

c = myclass()
print c
```

In the above example, I've overridden the object's default `__str__` implementation. `__str__` is what gets called when you try to represent the object as a string, or format it using a string formatting function.

BTW `repr` is what gets printed when you do `print obj`, it invokes the `__repr__` method on that object. See [the Python documentation of `__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for more information on how to control the formatting of objects.

```
# this would print the object's __repr__
print "%r" % c

# this would print the object's __str__
print "%s" % c
```

---

The output from the above code was

```
{'__class__': <class '__main__.myclass'>,
 '__delattr__': <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__dict__': {'bar': 'bar'},
 '__doc__': None,
 '__format__': <built-in method __format__ of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__getattribute__': <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__hash__': <method-wrapper '__hash__' of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__init__': <bound method myclass.__init__ of <__main__.myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>>,
 '__module__': '__main__',
 '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x82358a0>,
 '__reduce__': <built-in method __reduce__ of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__reduce_ex__': <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__repr__': <method-wrapper '__repr__' of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__setattr__': <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__sizeof__': <built-in method __sizeof__ of myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>,
 '__str__': <bound method myclass.__str__ of <__main__.myclass object at 0xb76deb0c>>,
 '__subclasshook__': <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x896ad34>,
 '__weakref__': None,
 'bar': 'bar',
 'foo': 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching about for this exactly myself, I came across this Dumper equivalent which I typically import now. https://salmon-protocol.googlecode.com/svn-history/r24/trunk/salmon-playground/dumper.py